# Create vector by conditions

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector `v`.

```
v <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A")
```

Now I would like equivalent vector `v'` that follows these conditions:

```
if v[i]=='A'
  then v'[i]='Q'
else v'[i]='P'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v1 <- c("A","B","C","C","B","A","A","C","A")
v2 <- rep("P", length(v1))
v2[v1 == "A"] <- "Q"
#> v2
#[1] "Q" "P" "P" "P" "P" "Q" "Q" "P" "Q"
```

---

Or

```
v2 <- ifelse(v1=="A","Q","P")
#[1] "Q" "P" "P" "P" "P" "Q" "Q" "P" "Q"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lookup vector, searching for elements of `v` that are not `A`.

```
v <- c("A","B","C","C","B","A","A","C","A")

c("Q", "P")[(v != "A") + 1L]
# [1] "Q" "P" "P" "P" "P" "Q" "Q" "P" "Q"
```